# How to html code a hidden field for a Sales Force contact form

Tags: input, hidden-field

I am creating 2 simple forms on a Wordpress web site using the Raw HTML element method in a Jupiter theme.

Sales Force want the lead source data to auto populate on their side without it being visible on the form itself.  As seen, or not seen, here: https://levelcapital.com/builder-short-form/
So the field is hidden, but not working correctly.

Here is what is there now but does NOT send Sales Force any data saying here is information from Level Capital referral partner form.

`````
````<input type="hidden" id="Lead Source" name="Lead_Source" value="Referral Partner" />````
`````

Here is that area's code that Sales Force gave me but it doesn't contain any "hidden" code, which of course, makes the form show a option value drop down menu. This is NOT supposed to show up.

`````
<option value="Manual">Manual</option>
<option value="Online Short App">Online Short App</option>
<option value="Sphere">Sphere</option>
</select>````

The intent is to have a builder client fill out the form, hit submit, Sales Force gets the data auto populated to their referral DB automatically.
`````